# Italics in title of Lattice graph

Tags: r, lattice, italics

I have read the posts on how to create italicized words in a graph title, but it does not seem to be working for me.

```
#create a list of species
sp <- c("Etelis coruscans","Etelis carbunculus","Pristipomoides sieboldii","Pristipomoides filamentosus","Pristipomoides zonatus","Epinephelus quernus","Aphareus rutilans")

#plot hisotgrams for each spp in 1cm bins
for (i in sp){
    BIN_WIDTH <- 1 #desired bin width
    print(histogram(~ Length..cm. | Method, #create and print the histogram and save to variable "graph"
    data = hist.data[hist.data$Scientific_name == i,], 
    nint = (max(hist.data$Length..cm.) - min(hist.data$Length..cm.)+1)/BIN_WIDTH,
    layout = c(1,2),
    main = paste("Length-Frequency of", italic(i), "by Gear"), sep = " ",
    xlab = "Length (cm)"))

    #save histogram to PNG file
    quartz.save(paste("*Length-Frequency of", i, "by method.png", sep = " "), type = "png")
    dev.off() #close the graphics diver
}
```

I get an error saying:

```
Error in print(histogram(~Length..cm. | Method, data = hist.data[hist.data$Scientific_name ==  : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'print': Error in paste(italic("Length-Frequency of", i, "by Gear")) : 
  could not find function "italic"
```

Can someone point out what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There argument you are passing to `main` needs a couple of changes.

- To use R's plotmath specials (i.e. things like `italic()`), it should be an expression object rather than a character string. That means doing something like this:

  ```
  main = expression(paste("Length-Freq of", italic("E. coruscans"), "by Gear"))
  ```

  instead of this:

  ```
  main = paste("Length-Freq of", italic("E. coruscans"), "by Gear")
  ```
- In addition, you are wanting to italicize `i`'s *value* rather than its *name*, but if you just type `italic(i)`, lattice will render `i`'s name as a little italic "*i*" for each species. Use `bquote()` or `substitute()` to substitute in `i`'s value instead, as demonstrated here:

  ```
  i <- "E. coruscans"
  xyplot(1:10~1:10,
      main = substitute(expr = expression(paste("Species name: ", italic(i))), 
                        env = list(i=i)))
  ```

[image]

Comment: PERFECT!  Here is the final working code:


main = substitute(expr = expression(paste("Length-Frequency of ", italic(i), " by Gear")), env = list(i=i)),