# italics and normal text in a main plot title

Tags: r, italics

I am plotting a graph in R but the italics function and it is being pretty frustrating under the main title:

Mapped territories of different *C. austriacus* individuals at the Far Gardens coral reef site

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You didn't give any information about your data but if the problem is italics in the title, maybe this code could help:

```
plot(rnorm(100), main = substitute(paste(italic('p value'), " = 0.01")))
```

[image]

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16659096/italics-in-title-of-lattice-graph).

Comment: Technically `plot()` isn't a lattice functions. Also, `plot(rnorm(100),main=expression(italic('p value') == 0.01 ))` would work just as well without the `paste()` since you're not really doing substitution. Though the OP will need paste to do `plot(rnorm(100),main=expression(paste("Mapped territories of different ", italic("C. austriacus"), " individuals at the Far Gardens coral reef site")))`

Comment: @MrFlick. You do not need quotes if you use proper plotmath separators.

Answer (score 19):

Personally I think using `paste` to construct plotmath expression is "ugly"; This is an alternative the more clearly demonstrates "clean" use of `expression`:

```
 plot(rnorm(100),main=expression( italic(p~value) == 0.01 ))
```

The other reason to use `expression` is that it will be accepted by Lattice functions whereas the `substitute` approach will not:

```
xyplot(1~1,main=substitute( paste(italic('p value'), " = 0.01" )))
#Error in paste(italic("p value"), " = 0.01") : 
#  could not find function "italic"
```

It would succeed if `expression()` were used inside the substitute call but it's excess baggage in that instance. I complained to Deepayan Sarkar once and his response was that `substitute` returns an unevaluated "call" rather than a true 'expression'.

Comment: Can I use expression and replace 0.01 with dynamically generated value?

Comment: You you can use `bquote` to do that at least with ordinary `plot`. Do a search on `[r] bquote title` for worked examples. There can be difficulties with lattice, so you might need to wrap as.expression around the result of bquote because the value it returns is technically not an R `'expression'`

Comment: for variables other option in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57455827/r-using-expression-in-plot-legends/63507326#63507326

Answer (score 6):

I think other users have answered this, but I found it not so cut and dry, and built off of their input because it gets tricky for long titles like the one in your example.

Here is the cleanest line of code I could conjure for combined italic/normal texts, using a generic plot... let me know how it works for your data (or anyone who reads this and finds it doesn't work with certain graphs, inbox me, I enjoy learning and would rather share than just store it in my noggin)

```
plot(1:10, main = expression('Mapped territories of different '*italic(C.~austriacus)*' individuals at the Far Gardens coral reef site'))
```

Now, to *line break* with **expression** or like terms that allow italicized or superscript/subscript text (other than simple labels), you can use the **atop** function to evenly break apart super long labels. One may prefer to use the preview app for final editing and labels, but if you want to stick to R for everything, you can use the following example:

```
plot(1:10, main = expression(atop('Mapped territories of different '*italic(C.~austriacus),  ' individuals at the Far Gardens coral reef site')))
```

which gives: 
[plot with long mixed title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naCFD.png)

Thanks to @42-

Comment: Cool stuff. Would this `atop` method also work with e.g. `ylab`?

Comment: actually i tried it without `atop`, just `expression` to insert italicized subscripts to `ylab` and it worked :)

Comment: cool, did it work with mixed text? (mixed as in italic text in between regular text?). If you have the line of code, I would enjoy to see it and try it myself.

Comment: yes it was mixed italic with normal text and even italic subscript.. i just put this into my `boxplot` function: `ylab=expression('Log of ('*italic(d[N])*'+0.01) / ('*italic(d[S])*'+0.01)')`

Comment: I was going to put here a little [demonstration](https://rnotebook.io/anon/e04c08fe0440e707/notebooks/formatting_in_plots.ipynb) but somehow the italics there doesn't work (but you can download the notebook, it works localy). I tweeted the Rnotebook author about this, maybe he'll know what's wrong there..