# R: using expression in plot legends

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to use the `legend` function in R. I want the label to read $\alpha = 1, \beta = 2$, so I tried using

```
legend("topleft", c(expression(alpha = 1, beta = 2)))
```

But that did not do the trick. Any advice?

What if I wanted my label to read $Gamma(\alpha = 1, \beta = 2)$? I tried

```
legend("topleft", c(paste("Gamma( ", expression(alpha = 1, beta = 2))))
```

Comment: The expression can be simplified to `legend("topleft", expression(Gamma(alpha == 1, beta == 2)) )`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can place everything within the `expression` itself

```
plot(1)
legend("topleft", expression(alpha~"= 1, "~beta~" = 2"))
```

[image]

---

If we need `Gamma(`

```
legend("topleft", expression(Gamma*"("*alpha~"= 1, "~beta~" = 2)"))
```

[image]

---

If we need the word `Gamma`

```
legend("topleft", expression("Gamma("*alpha~"= 1, "~beta~" = 2)"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. What if I wanted to write Gamma(\alpha = 1, \beta =2) instead? I tried using `paste("Gamma(", expression(...)))` but that didn't work.

Comment: @Adrian It should be inside the `expression`.  No need for `paste`

Comment: Thanks. But what if I want the word "Gamma" not the latex symbol $\gamma$? I realized that if I write `expression(Gamma())` it shows up as the latex symbol

Comment: You get typographically superior results if you use `group("(", ..., ")")` for parentheses and `==` for the equality sign, e.g., `expression("Gamma"*group("(", {alpha == 1 * ","~ beta == 2},")"))`.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is `str2lang`, which allows using variables

```
{
one<-1
two<-2
greek<-"Gamma"
greek1<-"alpha"
greek2<-"beta"
note <-  paste0(greek,"*'('*",greek1,"*' = ",one,", '*",greek2,"*' = ",two,")' " ) 
plot(1)
legend("topleft", legend=str2lang(paste0("paste(",note,")") ) )
}
```

[image]